# Vim interrupted after shell command

Tags: vim

I don't get why when I type something like :

```
:! bash -ic 'p4 diff %:p'
```

My Vim get interrupted and I get

```
[3]+  Stopped                 vim ~/.vimrc
```

as a consequence I have to put that job in foreground to see the effect of the command.

Do you know how can I solve this annoying issue ?

Comment: Why doesn't `:! p4 diff %:p` work for you?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling Vim to run an interactive command so it has no choice but to suspend itself to allow you to do what you want.

It's hard to be sure without more information about your setup but this command:

```
:!p4 diff %:p
```

should be enough to run `p4 diff` on the the current file without side-effects.